# Why can't you instantiate the same object of that class inside constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class Run{
 public static void main(String... args){
      A a1 = new A();
 }
}

class A{
  public A(){
    A a = new A();
  }
  //here as well A a = new A();
}
```

Why does this give a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`? Is there a recursive call happening here? How does it happen?

Comment: Step through your code mentally or on paper -- write down what is happening on paper with your constructor call and  you'll see the infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the constructor inside the constructor--that's what `new` does, constructs a new object.

Comment: is there any guess that how many times it will call constructor. if i use that for recursion.

Comment: @raghavendra Until you tell it to stop or the JVM blows up.

Comment: thank you for the reply. but in eclipse i see that program is running only for 6 to 7 times

Comment: Now i got it  thank you this is my work out                package tt.Exception;

public class Exe {
 static int x;
 Exe()
 {
  try {
   new Exe();
  } catch (java.lang.Error  e) {
   System.out.println("Runtime Error"+x++);
  }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Exe();
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a recursive call happening here?

Yup

> How it happens?

When you `new A()`, it calls the constructor for `A`, which does a `new A()` which calls the constructor, which does a `new A()` ... and so on.  That is recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You can call, but it would be a recursive calling which will run infinitely. That's why you got the `StackOverflowError`.

The following will work perfectly:

```
public class Run{

 static int x = 1;
 public static void main(String... args){
      A a1 = new A();
 }
}

class A{
   public A(){
     if(x==1){
        A a = new A();
        x++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you call the constructor, you create a new object (which means that you call the constructor again, so you create another object, so you call the constructor again...)

It is infinite recursion at its best, it is not related to it being a constructor (in fact you can create new objects from the constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Basically none of your constructors will ever exit - each will get as far as trying to instantiate another object of type `A` recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your constructor to actually create an `A` object. Suppose `A` holds an integer value and nothing more. In this case, your constructor should look like this:

```
class A{
  int number;
  public A(){
      number = 0;
  }
}
```

What you're doing in your code is actually creating a new object instance inside of your own constructor.

So, when you call `new A()`, you're calling the constructor, which then calls `new A()` inside of its body. It ends up calling itself infinitely, which is why your stack is overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that there's a recursive call there.  In order to create an A, you have to create another A inside of it.  But to create that A inside of it, you have to create a third A inside of that A.  And so on.  If you use two different constructors or arguments or something though, you should be able to work around this:

```
class A {
    public A(boolean spawn){
        if (spawn) {
            A a = new A(false);
        }
    }
}
```