# what will happen if Create same Object multiple times in main method and constructor as well

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class Assignment3{
Assignment3()
    {
        Assignment3 obj = new Assignment3();
    }
    
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Assignment3 obj = new Assignment3();
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

It's showing This :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError . What does it mean .

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364043/why-cant-you-instantiate-the-same-object-of-that-class-inside-constructor) answers this concern.

Comment: Why are you doing that?  What did you expect (or want) to happen?

Comment: It's an MCQ qtion . I was asked to guess the output